# Peltier pad issues

Tags: arduino

I am trying to make a Hot air balloon using [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07HQGPVDY) peltier pad connected to an arduino uno r3 by elegoo, which is powered by a duracell 9 volt battery. However, the peltier pad is not getting up to the desired temperature of around 80-90 C, and is cool enough that i can easily touch the hot side. I have already tried connecting 2 batteries to the pad, but that did not work either. Could someone please help me figure out how to achieve this? Thank you!